# Jquery achar o key a partir de um valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um array com valores que variam de acordo com a página.

Gostaria de saber como pegar o **key** de um valor específico.

Exemplo:

```
minhaarray = [5,10,15,20,25]
```

Como faço para extrair o **key** do valor 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você n precisa de jQuery ara isso, exite uma função nativa do prorpio JavaScript que já faz isso, é a `indexOf()`, segue um exemplo de como utiliza-lá

```
var minhaarray = [5,10,15,20,25];
var a = minhaarray.indexOf(15);
```

Nesse caso ira retornar 2, que é a posição que o número 15 está no array.

Caso você realmente queira utilizar o jQuery, existe uma função deles chamada `inArray()`, que no caso você informa o valor e o array e ele retorna a posição que o mesmo se encontra, ex:

```
var arr = [ 4, 5, 8, 9 ];
jQuery.inArray( 8, arr );
```

Obs: tanto a função `indexOf()` e `inArray()` retornam -1 caso o valor não seja localizado dentro do array

Comment: Funcionou muito bem o indexOf, muito obrigado pela luz, abração